# Run emacs lisp script

Tags: debugging, emacs

I found the [script](http://correl.phoenixinquis.net/2015/07/12/git-graphs.html) and i need run it.

I tried to run it like this (i used eval-buffer command):

```
(require 'subr-x)
(require 's)
(load-file "~/git-graph.el")
(require 'git-graph)
(git-graph/to-graphviz-pretty
 "git"
 (git-graph/git-graph-head
  "E:/GitStack/repositories/gitRepo.git"
  "master"))
```

But get an error:

```
Loading e:/emHome/git-graph.el (source)...done
let*: Symbol’s function definition is void: first
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IodUv.png)

Please tell me what is wrong. And how i can run this script?

I'm new to this.

Comment: What version of emacs do you run? `first` is normally an alias for `car`.

Comment: You need to find out what library defines `first` as a function or macro -- it needs to be processed *before* `git-graph` is used.  Word search for `defun first` and `defmacro first` until you find it, and then `require` that library if it is in your load path or use `load` without `require`.  There is no need to `load` something and then `require` it afterwords.  If you don't have the library that defines `first`, then figure out where it is on the internet and/or via the package manager and install it.

Comment: @choroba , GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading library `git-graph` twice?

1. What happens if you just remove either the `load-library` line or the `require` line -- do you still get an error?
2. With your original code, insert this line after the `load-library` line:

   ```
   (message "After load-library")
   ```

   And insert this line after the `require` line:

   ```
   (message "After require")
   ```

   See which message(s) you get: check buffer `*Messages*`. That should tell you which attempt to load the library (if either) led to the error.  Maybe look for the text `first` in the library, to see if you notice anything funny.

   If it doesn't look like the problem comes from loading that library then it likely comes from the expression after your `require`.
3. Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, then do your `M-x eval-buffer`, and post the `*Backtrace*` output here. That will show us just where the error is raised.
4. You can also try `M-x debug-on-entry git-graph/to-graphviz-pretty` and step through the debugger using `d` (or `c` to skip details of a given step). That will eventually show you which code raised the error.

Comment: 1) Removing `require` did not change anything. 2) All messages are displayed. 3) [stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/1pL8QFWU)

Comment: That suggests that: (1) you don't need to load it twice: the `require` should suffice. (2) Loading the library is not the problem. (3) The problem is in the expression you evaluate after loading the library. (4) So do what is suggested in #3 or #4 of the answer.